# Android FirebaseUi cusomization

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm using firebaseUi for authentication and i need to make the confirm panel's (Alert dialog) background to be dark or the text to be light whatever makes it visible.
Is there any xml attribute should i add/remove to handle this?

[image]

My FirebaseUi styles:

```
<style name="LoginTheme" parent="FirebaseUI">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="FirebaseUI.Text">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="FirebaseUI.Text.Link">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorSecondary</item>
</style>
```